# Scala-Spark Dynamically call groupby and agg with parameter values

Tags: scala, apache-spark, group-by, customization, aggregate

I want to write a custom grouping and aggregate function to get user specified column names and user specified aggregation map.**I do not know the column names and aggregation map up front**. I want to write a function similar to something like below. But i am new to Scala and i cannot solve it.

```
def groupAndAggregate(df: DataFrame,  aggregateFun: Map[String, String], cols: List[String] ): DataFrame ={
  val grouped = df.groupBy(cols)
  val aggregated = grouped.agg(aggregateFun)
  aggregated.show()
}
```

and want to call it like

```
val listOfStrings =  List("A", "B", "C")
val result = groupAndAggregate(df, Map("D"-> "SUM", "E"-> "COUNT"), listOfStrings)
```

How can i do this?
Can anyone help me please.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code is almost correct - with two issues:

1. The return type of your function is `DataFrame`, but the last line is `aggregated.show()`, which returns `Unit`. Remove the call to `show` to return `aggregated` itself, or just return the result of `agg` immediately
2. `DataFrame.groupBy` expects arguments as follows: `col1: String, cols: String*` - so you need to pass matching arguments: the first columns, and then the rest of the columns as a list of arguments, you can do that as follows: `df.groupBy(cols.head, cols.tail: _*)`

Altogether, your function would be:

```
def groupAndAggregate(df: DataFrame,  aggregateFun: Map[String, String], cols: List[String] ): DataFrame ={
  val grouped = df.groupBy(cols.head, cols.tail: _*)
  val aggregated = grouped.agg(aggregateFun)
  aggregated
}
```

Or, a similar shorter version:

```
def groupAndAggregate(df: DataFrame,  aggregateFun: Map[String, String], cols: List[String] ): DataFrame = {
  df.groupBy(cols.head, cols.tail: _*).agg(aggregateFun)
}
```

If you *do* want to call `show` within your function:

```
def groupAndAggregate(df: DataFrame,  aggregateFun: Map[String, String], cols: List[String] ): DataFrame ={
  val grouped = df.groupBy(cols.head, cols.tail: _*)
  val aggregated = grouped.agg(aggregateFun)
  aggregated.show()
  aggregated
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. Yes. `df.groupBy(cols.head, cols.tail: _*)` this is what mainly i couldn't think of. The second version is what i needed. The rest is just for local testing.

Comment: For me it worked like                                                                                    val key=List("key1","key2")                                                                          val grouped = df.groupBy(cols.head, cols: _*)